# Inserting result of a table into another table with two foreach loops

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert, entity-relationship

I am trying to get the result of a table and insert it into another table. The results are user id's.  This code should work, but it doesn't.

```
$query1 = "SELECT id FROM users";                           
$select1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$select1->execute(array());  
foreach($select as $index => $rs) {

    $users = $rs['id'];

    // the results are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8... (the user id's)

}



// Here below, I want to add the results into another table...

foreach ($users as $row){
    $query2 = "INSERT INTO validateuser (userid) VALUES (".$row.")";

    $select2 = $db->prepare($query2);
    $select2->execute(array());  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems over-complicated to me. Why not let the database do what databases do best - handle data, and perform this in a single insert-select statement?

```
INSERT INTO validateuser (userid)
SELECT id FROM users
```

**EDIT:**

To answer the concern raised in the comments, the `'validated'` value could be selected as a literal:

```
INSERT INTO validateuser (userid, validated)
SELECT id, 'validated' FROM users
```

Comment: INSERT INTO validateuser (userid)
SELECT id FROM users ? I have never seen a query like this before. What do you mean? How can I enter all I want in one query?

Comment: @J.Doe exactly. You can learn more about this in [MySQL's documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html)

Comment: Because I have other values to enter in the same table for other columns. All of the users must have a text called 'validated' inserted on a second column. This must be for all user id's. Your code works but I don't know if I can do what I want with your suggestion.

Comment: INSERT INTO validateuser (userid, secondvalue)
SELECT id FROM users, "validated";      something like this...

Comment: This is so good. Can I also join two tables? For example ...Select users.id, 'validated', customers.id from users join customers... Is something like this possible too?

Comment: @J.Doe yes. Whatever you can do in a normal `select`, you can also use in an insert-select statement.

Answer (score 1):

As you iterate the results of the first query with `foreach($select as $index => $rs)`, you set `$users` to the id of each row of the results with `$users = $rs['id'];`.

At the end of your loop, `$users` will contain the id of the last row because it's being overwritten each time. It's not iterable (it's an int), so `foreach ($users as $row){` doesn't make sense.

You probably meant to do `$users[] = $rs['id'];` instead. But if you're just inserting them all, you might as well just do it in one query like the other answer suggests.